# Wordpress User specific downloadable content

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a section to my website that has downloadable content that is user specific.

I have made a custom post type with a field for uploading the downloadable file and a field for selecting the user (using Advanced Custom Field) but I'm unclear on how to filter out the users who I want to allow to see the downloads.

Comment: there are many plugins doing this... try searching "user specific content"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
    <?php

    $user = get_field('user'); // user is the name of your field ACF
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // the current user

    if ( $current_user->ID == $user ) {
        echo 'show custom post here ! ';
    } 
    ?>
```